# Install Texlive in manjaro via iso

Tags: software-installation, manjaro

I have the TeXlive .iso file and a Manjaro linux distro. I tried to run the install.sh script from the iso file, with `./install.sh` after `chmod +x`.

Apparently this doesn't install the TeXlive.

Should I install through the command line?

Answer (score 0):

I am using texlive without any problems in manjaro. Make sure the iso is mounted, cd to where it has been mounted and ./install.sh should work.